# Are all functions in JavaScript essentially methods?

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, window

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and programming in general. I'm trying to understand more about how JavaScript works. Based on my understanding of methods and functions, and if I open my in browser console and type

```
typeof(this);
//=> "object" 
console.log(this); 
//=> Window {top: Window, window:Window, location:Location, external: Object, chrome: Object,...}
```

I am seeing the global object Window. Since subsequent functions are just methods from the host window object, aren't all functions essentially methods in JavaScript?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, functions are methods, variables are properties.

Comment: What's the difference between a method and a function?

Comment: Maybe this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) helps?

Comment: @dollarvar: Variables are properties? That's not true unless you're talking about global variables, in which case they're properties of the global object.

Comment: @cookiemonster You got me on that one (confused it with "object orientated" languages like PHP). Actually a `length` thing is a property in Javascript... ;) http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_intro.asp 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECMAScript defines `method` as a function that is accessed as the property of an object. So it's more how it's referenced that makes the difference than what it is.

> **[ECMAScript 4.3.27](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.27)**
> **[method](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.27)**
>
> *function that is the value of a property.*

---

> *"Since all other subsequent objects and functions (which are objects) are just parasites from the host window, aren't functions methods in JavaScript?"*

Don't know what you mean by "parasites", but as shown above, functions *can be* methods if they're the value of a property.

If you're talking about global functions, then that's a unique situation since they can be accessed as both variables and properties of the global object, so I'd say that whether you'd refer to it as a method would depend on how you're accessing it.

---

Don't rely on your logging of `this`. The way `this` works in JavaScript is such that it's a very dynamic value that isn't permanently bound to any particular object for a given method or function. *(That is unless you used `.bind()` to create the function object.)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer @cookie-- I'm still confused as to why I could make a function in the console, let's say `var dogs = function (){ alert('woof, woof!')}` then `window.dogs.call()` and have it bark. If it's not a value of a property of the window object, then why can I access it using dot notation?

Comment: and 'parasites' was in reference to the domain specific nature of JavaScript needing the Window object to inhabit as opposed to a global namespace.

Comment: @Gina: All global variables are at the same time a property of the window object. Every lexical environment has an internal object used to store the local variables. This object is *not* accessible. However, the object that holds the global variables is accessible. As such, you can access globals both as variables and as properties of that global object. If you did `window.cat = function() { alert("meow"); })`, you can access the function as a global variable. `cat.call()` or just `cat()`.

Comment: This answer is NOT correct. Anonymous functions are not value of a property.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, functions are methods in Javascript. There is no difference.

Comment: In strict mode they differ.

Comment: My question wasn't whether they were the same. Rather, that there aren't any functions in JS at all. It seems like there is a function operator, to which I can pair a reference name or leave anonymous, and methods.

Comment: @Givi could you explain why they differ in strict mode.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not psychic. "aren't functions methods in JavaScript?"

Comment: @Gina: There's no difference in strict mode. A function's `this` value may differ, but that doesn't have any impact on whether or not it's a method. Don't know what Givi was thinking of.

Comment: @Gina My bad, I misunderstood a question.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the answer is NO, not all functions are methods in JavaScript.

Follow through:

```
var myMathObject = {
    pi: 3.14,
    add: function(a,b) {
        return a + b
    }
}
myMathObject.add(3,4) // 7
```

In the above example, `add` is a function and since it belongs to `myMathObject`, that makes it also a method. That's why we are referencing is with a dot between the object and the function as `myMathObject.add`. If you are in same execution context, you don't need to access the method with a dot.

```
function add(a,b) {
    return a + b
}
add(3,4) // 7
window.add(3,4) // 7
window.add == add // true
```

So the `add` function is also a method, a method of global object, in this case `window`.

Since we are always in a context of an object, that makes it impossible to declare a function outside an object in JavaScript, this leads us thinking that all functions are also a method but this is not correct.

ECMAScript defines method as "function that is the value of a property", According to this definition, if a function is not a value of a property, then it is not a method. **That means anonymous functions are not methods**. That makes sense since they are not accessible with dot notation. Also Immediately-invoked function expressions (IIFE) are not methods, because they are also anonymous functions.

```
(function (a,b) {
    return a + b
})(3,4) // 7

window. ? // how to access it?
```

That makes the answer clear: **NO, not all JavaScript functions are methods.**